# how to write msword template using jtextarea?

Tags: java, ms-word

I have 5 Jtextfield and one button...so after clicking button want to display all these textfields data on msworld template...here i tried this code but when I open doc file I got only last textfield data on template but want all textfields. so not able to recognize this issue.

File file = new File("e:/ExportFromJTable/quotation.doc");

```
public void writeDoc(String FileName, String content)
{
try 
    {
        POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem();
        DirectoryEntry directory = fs.getRoot();
        directory.createDocument("WordDocument", new ByteArrayInputStream(content.getBytes()));
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(FileName);
        fs.writeFilesystem(out);
        out.close();
    } catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) 
            {

```
                String text = qdata.getText();
                String amt = amount.getText()
                String f = file.getPath();
                writeDoc(f, text);
                writeDoc(f, amt);
                System.out.println("word file created");
```

}

On template I got only amount not qdata.

Comment: Every time you open the file and write it, you're overwriting what was previously there

Comment: Okay, so how i keep only one file for all textfilds? Please ellaborate.

Comment: Open the file one, write what you want to the file, close it

Comment: can you provide code?

Comment: @mad programmer thank you...problem resolve..